# ReactJS - component does not load with url parameter

Tags: reactjs

Component does not load when I manually enter a url with parameter in the browser's search bar and naturally it says 'not working' in the console but when I click on a button going to '/:username' url from my index page, I don't get any error, it works pretty well. Where am I wrong?

**router.js**

```
const Main = () => (

<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/login" component={FrontLogin} />
  <Route path="/register" component={FrontRegister} />
    <IndexRoute exact path="/home" component={FrontHome} />
    <IndexRoute exact path="/:username" component={FrontProfile} />
    <Redirect to="/home" />
  </Switch>

)
```

**index.js**

```
class Index extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <Provider {...Store}>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Route component= {Main}/>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </Provider>
        )
    }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Index/>,document.getElementById('index'))
```

**profile.index.js**

```
const Profile = (props) => {
    const {params} = props.match;
    const [data, setData] = useState({});
    const history = useHistory();
    const [refresh, setRefresh] = useState(false);

console.log(props);
if(!props.location.key){
    console.log('not working');
}

if (props.location.key) {
    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get(
                `/api/${params.username}`,

                {
                    headers: {
                        Authorization:
                            "Bearer " +
                            props.AuthStore.appState.user.access_token,
                    },
                }
            )
            .then((res) => {
                if (res.data.username) {
                    setData(res.data);
                    setRefresh(true);
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }, [refresh]);
}

console.log(refresh);
```

**ProvideRoute.js**

```
const PrivateRoute = ({
    component:Component,
    path,
    ...rest
}) => (
    <Route path= {path} {...rest}
    render={
        props => isLoggedIn ? (
            <Component {...props}/>
        ) : (
            <Redirect to={{
                pathname:"/login",
                state:{
                    prevLocation:path,
                    error:'Giriş yapmalısın.'
                }
            }}/>
        )
    } />
)

export default withRouter(PrivateRoute);
```

Comment: `when I manually enter a url with parameter` - can you add the url you are accessing to the question?

Comment: It happens sometimes based on the configuration. Please provide more details about your config. Is this happening in the development or the production mode? Are you using a reverse proxy, Nginx?

Comment: for example when i enter a url like this: `localhost:8000/test` @K41F4r

Comment: i updated. i added PrivateRoute @fsefidabi

Comment: Why are you putting `Main` into a route and not just rendering it? If you then go to `localhost:8000/login` - after making this change - what do you get?

Comment: that's why am I using PrivateRoute. PrivateRoute prevents this. i'm so beginner in react so I could be wrong.

Comment: where do you use `PrivateRoute` ? What is the `IndexRoute` in the `router.js`?